# HTML forms local storage

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have recently made a quick HTML form for my FRC Team (FIRST Robotics Team) to evaluate other teams and their robots at competition. Currently, the form submits to a MySQL server, which is what we want, the problem is, we won't be connected to the internet at all times, so we want to be able to locally store the information from multiple forms, then once the user has a WiFi connection, they dump the entire collection of filled out forms onto the MySQL. I'm not very experienced in programming, so a simple solution would be preferred, but anything that works would be appreciated. The form in it's current state can be found at:

www.avirez.com/scouting

The PHP looks like this:

```
 <?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("sqlStuff","moreSQL","evenMore","lastOne");

// Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

 $sql="INSERT INTO scouting_data (teamName, teamNumber, auto, truss, high, low, human, self, robotNotes, togethor, others, teamNotes)
 VALUES
 ('$_POST[teamName]','$_POST[teamNumber]','$_POST[auto]','$_POST[truss]','$_POST[high]','$_POST[low]','$_POST[human]','$_POST[self]','$_POST[robotNotes]','$_POST[togethor]','$_POST[others]','$_POST[teamNotes]')";

 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
   }
mail("MyEmail@gmail.com","New data submission","A form has been submitted to the FRC        Scouting database","");
header("Location: thanks.html");

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no internet connection, how do they get to the form? is it running on local?

If it is, then maybe a good solution is to add in the case of "no access to database" a simple write to a csv and then add a button in the form for "send no-connection data". En example using your code could be:

```
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   //echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   $handle = fopen("noconnection.txt",'w+');
   fputcsv($handle, [
    $_POST[teamName],$_POST[teamNumber],
    $_POST[auto],$_POST[truss],
    $_POST[high],$_POST[low],
    $_POST[human],$_POST[self],
    $_POST[robotNotes],$_POST[togethor],
    $_POST[others],$_POST[teamNotes]
    ]);
   fclose($handle);
   }
```

and then create another script for the new button that will read the file and save it to the database:

```
if (($handle = fopen("noconnection.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $sql="INSERT INTO scouting_data (teamName, teamNumber, auto, truss, high, low, human, self, robotNotes, togethor, others, teamNotes)
             VALUES
             (".$data[0].",".data[1]....and so on...

             if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
               {
               die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
               }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

its not the most elegant of solutions, but i think its the easier.
hope it helps.